# Create a macro that appends some code an existing command, with arguments

Tags: macros, etoolbox

As I am working on improving my answer to [Different approach to literate programming for LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50336/2975), I have created a macro that automatically processes two arguments and formats indexes accordingly. The arguments are strings (not control sequences), with `#1` being the type of macro and `#2` being the name of the macro.

Here is a sample of the macro I am using. It relies on `etoolbox` and `xstring`.

```
\newcommand{\set@macro@type}[2]{
    \StrSubstitute{#2}{@}{"@}[\entryname]
    % Default definitions
    \def\macro@type{#1}
    \def\macro@format{#2}
    \def\macro@index{#2@\string\texttt{#2}}
    % Specific type definitions
    \ifstrequal{#1}{m}
        {\def\macro@type{}
         \def\macro@format{\textbackslash#2}
         \def\macro@index{%
            \entryname @\string\texttt{{\string\textbackslash}\entryname}}}{}
    \ifstrequal{#1}{l}
        {\def\macro@type{length}
         \def\macro@format{%
            \entryname @\string\texttt{{\string\textbackslash}\entryname}}}{}
    \ifstrequal{#1}{e}
        {\def\macro@type{environment}
         \def\macro@format{\textbackslash#2\par\textbackslash end#2}
         \def\macro@index{%
            \entryname @\string\texttt{{\string\textbackslash}\entryname}}}{}}
```

However, I would like to make it so that the user can add new types of macros with an interface such as:

```
\addmacro{<name>}{<type>}{<format>}{<index>}
```

which should append the following code to my existing macro:

```
\ifstrequal{#1}{<name>}
    {\def\macro@type{<type>}
     \def\macro@format{<format>}
     \def\macro@index{<index>}}
```

Ideally, the `\addmacro` command could be starred, too, as I have an additional switch to toggle depending on the user's wishes.

So, my question is: how can I implement a macro that appends some code at the end of the main macro, and that can be used repeatedly. I would prefer to keep using `etoolbox` if possible (I have seen `\apptocmd` in the documentation but can't get it to work). The main difficulty which I am encountering is with the arguments `#1` and `#2` of `\set@macro@style`, which the user must be able refer to in some way. How could this be implemented? An explanation would be very welcome too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably place an empty macro without arguments (`\setmacrotypeend`) at the end of `\set@macro@type` and append code to this with `\ltx@GlobalAppendToMacro` from the [ltxcmds](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxcmds) package. About necessary expansion see [Comparing an argument to a string when argument is a result of a command with etoolbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24922/comparing-an-argument-to-a-string-when-argument-is-a-result-of-a-command-with-et). I did *not* test this, but for a comment it is too long and needs too much format.

```
\newcommand{\setmacrotypeend}{}

\newcommand{\set@macro@type}[2]{
... (unchanged as it was before)
\def\setmacrotypefirstargument{#1}
\setmacrotypeend%
}

\RequirePackage{ltxcmds}

\newcommand{\addmacro}[4]{%
\ltx@GlobalAppendToMacro{\setmacrotypeend}{%
  \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\setmacrotypefirstargument}{#1}
    {\def\macro@type{#2}
     \def\macro@format{#3}
     \def\macro@index{#4}}
}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I adapted the general idea to `etoolbox` and it works fine. One question however: do you know how I should write a boolean switch in `\addmacro` (created earlier with `newif`, so something like `\thingtrue`)? `\expandafter` does not work there.

Comment: @ienissei `\newif\ifname   \newcommand{\addmacro}[4]{\ltx@GlobalAppendToMacro{\setmacrotypeend}{\ifname ... \else
...\fi}} \nametrue or \namefalse` seems to work, i.e. I just do not understand it at the moment. Could you ask this as new question, please? (Even if I still would not see the issue, surely somebody here will provide a solution, which is more unlikely for a question in a comment.) (Maybe I should just get some sleep, better yet, should have gotten more of it last night, sorry.)

Comment: Sure, thank you for your answer :). I will give it a bit more thought and eventually ask a new question about it.