# StrSubstitute and @ inside and outside \lstnewenvironment

Tags: listings, catcodes, xstring

While further working on code for my answer to [Different approach to literate programming for LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47237/10119), I am encountering a problem to which I am sure there is a very simple solution, but it completely escapes me.

The issue is: I want to be able to automatically index macro names, some of which will contain the `@` character; hence, I need to preprocess them and substitute `@` with `"@` for `makeindex` to accept them. I have some code that works *while* in a `listings` environment but not when used in a normal environment or command (and I need them too). What's more, if I try to replace any normal letter, it works everywhere – it's only the `@` that doesn't work.

So, I suspect the answer has got something to do with `listings` doing some wizardry on the catcodes, but I would like to find out what it is and how to reproduce it.

Here is the minimal (in which I am reproducing the actual structure of my code, in case the problem lies somewhere there):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,etoolbox,xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\set@macro@type}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{@}{"@}[\entryname]}
\newcommand{\processtexcs}[1]{\set@macro@type{#1}}
\newcommand{\maketexcs}[1]{\forcsvlist{\par\processtexcs{#1}}\entryname}
\makeatother

\lstnewenvironment{code}[1]
    {\maketexcs{#1}}
    {}
\newenvironment{notcode}[1]
    {\maketexcs{#1}}
    {}
\newcommand{\command}[1]{\maketexcs{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}{my@first@macro}
\end{code}

\begin{notcode}{my@second@macro}
\end{notcode}

\command{my@third@macro}

\end{document}
```

(Note that it all works if you replace the `@` with `y` in `\StrSubstitute`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *your* wizardry on the category codes. :)

You're defining the main macro in a context where `@` has category code 11; but when you use it, `\StrSubstitute` can't find a category code 11 `@`. Use

```
\newcommand{\setmacrotype}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{@}{"@}[\entryname]}
\newcommand{\processtexcs}[1]{\setmacrotype{#1}}
\newcommand{\maketexcs}[1]{\forcsvlist{\par\processtexcs{#1}}\entryname}
```

without any `\makeatletter`.

If you're in a `.cls` or `.sty` file and want to keep the internal name `\set@macro@type`, then

```
\begingroup\lccode`?=`@ \lowercase{\endgroup
  \newcommand{\set@macro@type}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{?}{"?}[\entryname]}
}
```

will do. The `\lowercase` operation will transform `?` (which has category code 12) into a category code 12 `@` *before* processing `\endgroup` and `\newcommand`. Only character tokens are affected by `\lowercase`, so the list of possibly changed tokens is `{[1]#}?"` and only `?` (under the default setting) will be "lowercased" according to the previous assignment.

Comment: Thanks a million :) Since I am in a class file, the `\makeatletter` of the MWE wasn't technically wrong, but I altered the catcodes manually in `\maketexcs` and it all works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: @ienissei I've added a way to do it without too many somersaults.